# Storing arrays to localStorage every click of a button

Tags: jquery, local-storage

I want to save each ID when I click a button to a lolalStorage.

```
 $("li").on("click", "a", function(){
     var test = {"id":  id, "name":name}; 
     localStorage.setItem("test", JSON.stringify(test));
 });
```

But on page reload, I can only get one id.

Comment: If you store your data on the same variable e.g. `test` then you will only be storing one object, the last one saved. You need to use different keys possibly based on the id of your objects, to store different objects and be able to retrieve them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are overriding the same item on every click, so you only store  the last one. `test` is the key of this value.

You have two options:

1.- Use the `id` to store the information in the localStorage or generate a new object with the information.

Using `id` as a localStorage key:

```
 $("li").on("click", "a", function(){
     localStorage.setItem(id, name);
 });
```

This way you won't know which id's you already have in the localStorage, so it's complicated to retrieve the information afterwards.

2.- Another option is to save an array with all the key-value objects. You will only store one object in localStorage that contains multiple objects:

```
 $("li").on("click", "a", function(){
     var test = localStorage.getItem("test");
     var obj = [];
     if(test){
         obj= JSON.parse(test);  
     }
     obj.push({"id":  id, "name":name});
     localStorage.setItem("test",JSON.stringify(obj));
 });
```

So then to retrieve the information is as easy as doing:

```
 var test = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("test"));  // Returns array with multiple objects
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CgpeF/

Comment: if im gonna use option number 1, how am i gonna retrieve the value?

Comment: This is what I'm pointing out in the comment. You probably won't know which id's you have already stored..

Comment: hi, your explanation makes sense, however there's an error using method push.

Comment: hey, thank you very much for your help. i fixed the error. turned out it was a typo. thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Since localStorage is using the same key "test" every time, you're overwriting the same value with every click.  Try using

```
localStorage.setItem(id, name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could save the previous localstorage into a variable then combine it with your new data. Something like this:

```
 $("li").on("click", "a", function(){
       /* get the previously saved local storage */
       var previouslocalstorage = localStorage.getItem("test");

       /*get the new test data */
       var newtest = JSON.stringify({"id":  id, "name":name});            

       /*join the previous and the new to localstorage */
       localStorage.setItem("test", previouslocalstorage + newtest);
 });
```

This should now save each new set of test data